# Cordova cannot be upgraded at Intel xdk

Tags: intel, cordova-plugins, intel-xdk

Im very new to Intel Xdk .
can someone tell me how to upgrade Intel XDK Cordova 3.3 to Cordova 3.5 ?

screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTEyD.jpg

thank you.

Comment: you can change cli version in project settings, but as I see, for now XDK can't build with CLI 3.5.1 or 3.5. I have errors with my few test apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

projects->build settings->android->Cordova cli version-> change 3.3 to 3.5
they said at the forum that when you type 3.5 it actually install 3.5.1